# How to merge two branches, with a new target added on 2nd branch?

Tags: ios, atlassian-sourcetree, xcode8.2

I am trying to merge two branches using "cherry pick" operation on a commit in which new target is added in project. On merging this commit to first branch generates so many conflicts & becomes very difficult to merge.Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the conflicts appear in your `.xcodeproj` file: in branch A you added a new target and possible some other stuff, and in branch B you also made some changes. If the changes in B are simple (e.g. you just added or removed files), you can use this "brute force" strategy:

1. Instead of merging the two versions of `.xcodeproj`, just use the version from A, dropping all changes in B.
2. Then manually re-apply the changes from B; the compiler will help you to some extent by pointing out which files are missing.

If you don't have too many changes to re-apply, this can be a faster approach than to merge every single conflict.

Comment: I have added a new target along with separate assets for the same in branch B & I want to merge it in branch A.